# Jquery - Scrollbar to move div's backroundPosition horizontally

Tags: jquery

I am trying to work out how to have my **body scrollbar** move the **backgroundPosition** of a particular div - **#simpleBG** - to the right as it scrolls down and to the left as it scrolls up.

> jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
>
> ```
>       $('#simpleBG').scroll(function(event, direction) {
>      if (direction === 'down') {
>         $('#simpleBG').animate({backgroundPosition: '-=20px 0px'})
>      }
>      else {
>         $('#simpleBG').animate({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'})
>      }        });
> ```
>
> });

I have backroundpos.js to allow for background animation. Just unsure if I'm using the right logic and syntax here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
   var $simpleBG = $("#simpleBG"),
       $root = $(".wrapper");

   $root.on("scroll", (function(e,d) {
       if(d=='down'){
          $simpleBG.animate{backgroundPosition: '-=20px 0px'})
       }
       else {
          $simpleBG.animate({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'})
       }        
   });
```

Where .wrapper is a class on your outer element.

Not too sure about the direction on the scroll element though, another solution for the direction could be:

```
var tempScrollTop, currentScrollTop = 0;

   $("#div").scroll(function(){

   currentScrollTop = $("#div").scrollTop();

   if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop )
   //scrolling down
   else if (tempScrollTop > currentScrollTop )
   //scrolling up

tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
}
```